# what does "accounts of" mean in the context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> There is a growing focus on digitisation, datafication, automation and artificial intelligence in migration studies. This report reviews **accounts** of these technological innovations with a particular emphasis on their impacts for how migration is conceived and governed.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Did you look for the word in a dictionary? Didn't you find the word or didn't you find a definition that suited your sentence? Please read the [help centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) and especially the [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section. You can edit and improve your question by clicking on "edit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"accounts of" in this context could be read as "stories about" or "reports about". In other words, "accounts" is being used not in the sense of "counting" or anything financial, but in the sense of "reports" or "explanations".